# Как в $.ajax() дождаться readyState 4

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый день!
Для примера дана функция

```
function Test(){
var req = $ajax(...);
req.done({function(responce){
console.log(responce);
});
return ...
};
```

В таком случае функция вернет что-либо не дожидаясь того как запрос выполнится и отдаст readyState: 4;
Собственно вопрос в следующем. Как дождаться readyState 4 перед тем как продолжать выполнение после ajax?

Comment: никак, и его не надо дожидаться. Когда readyState == 4 запрос завершился, следовательно выполнится коллбэк переданный в функцию `done`(если все хорошо) и все что нужно делать по завершении запроса можно делать в нем.

Answer (score -1):

Решение (тестировалось на `jQuery 2.0.2`)

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        var self = this;
        var xhr = settings.xhr;
        settings.xhr = function () {
            var output = xhr();
            output.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (typeof(self.readyStateChanged) == "function") {
                    self.readyStateChanged(this);
                }
            };
            return output;
        };
    },
    readyStateChanged: function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            /* Do something */
        }
    },
    url: "..."
});
```